# Связка Андроид приложения и MSQL Server 2014

Tags: java, android-studio

Никак не могу связать приложение с Msql server 2014. 
Вопроc: связать можно любой выпуск MSQL или только Express ?

Comment: а ка вы это собрались делать? Sql Server на Android нет

Comment: в Android Studio пишу приложение скачал библиотеку jtds-1.3.1.jar с помощью него хотел с msql server извлекать данные .

Comment: MS SQL не поддерживает Android (и очень сомневаюсь, что когда-либо будет поддерживать)

Comment: Как нет множество примеров в интернете http://streletzcoder.ru/rabotaem-s-bazami-dannyih-v-java-na-primere-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: @ХикматШайхалиев по приведённой вами ссылке пример для обычных операционных систем, не для Android.

Comment: @ХикматШайхалиев не вижу проблем приконектится посредством какого либо `jdbc` драйвера если android устройство находится в одной сети с `MS SQL` сервером.